# Infinite redirection when using $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I have faced some problem trying to setup angular routing.
I have an application that is bootstrapped by hand (I need this feature, because I already have html5 navigation throughout whole site, and want angular to work only on certain page - it works fine).
But when I run my code I got some issues:

- if `.otherwise` provided, I got infinite loop calling my controller and dying with Range error in Chrome
- and I always got url redirection from hash version to non hash, even if I call `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`

Guess issues may be caused by fact that I am already using history.js and event handlers for statechange events, but for now I'm stuck with no clues.
Need your help to got some answer.

Thanks for your time.

And code.

**HTML**

```js
<script>
    if (typeof angular === 'undefined')
    {
        Modernizr.load({
            load: [
                '/static/css/angular.css',
                '/static/js/libs/angular/angular.min.js',
                '/static/js/files/angular/app.js',
                '/static/js/files/angular/controllers.js',
                '/static/js/files/angular/filters.js',
                '/static/js/files/angular/services.js',
                '/static/js/libs/angular/angular-resource.min.js',
            ],
            complete: function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('manager'), ['manager']);
            }
        });
    } else {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('manager'), ['manager']);
        });
    }
</script>
```

**app.js**

```js
/* App Module */

var FM = angular.module('manager', ['managerFilters'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/home', { controller: FilesListCtrl, templateUrl: '/static/partials/1.html' })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
        }]);
```

**controllers.js**

```js
function FilesListCtrl($scope, $filter, $routeParams) {
    app.log('FilesListCtrl')
}
```

Comment: Try taking everything out but the bare essentials. I mean, set up just what you need to do the routing, ditch Modernizr etc. See if it works. If it doesn't set up some break points in Chrome's dev tools. It's really hard to see without seeing your entire app.

Comment: Have u actually tried to start your app outside of the site? I mean u say the problem is probably caused by history.js, deactivate it and see if AngularJS works.

Comment: Yeah, thanks guys. It is really history.js that messes everything. Once I've disabled it both problems went away - hashes are working, and no infinite loop with `.otherwise`. Would you mind to add this as answer so I'll be able to accept one?

Comment: If the problem is solved post an answer and accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@blesh @Flek thank you.

It was history.js to blame. When you try to use angular routing with it you'll have no option to set
`$locationProvider.html5Mode` to `false`. And other bugs occur like infinite redirection with default route provided.